# Progress bar not appearing bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm following [this](http://dotnetspeak.com/2013/05/creating-simple-please-wait-dialog-with-twitter-bootstrap/comment-page-1) tutorial for displaying a progress bar.

**test.js**

```
var waitBar;
waitBar = waitBar || (function () {
    var pleaseWaitDiv = $('<div class="modal hide" id="pleaseWaitDialog" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false"><div class="modal-header"><h1>Processing...</h1></div><div class="modal-body"><div class="progress progress-striped active"><div class="bar" style="width: 100%;"></div></div></div></div>');
    return {
        showPleaseWait: function () {
            pleaseWaitDiv.modal();
        },
        hidePleaseWait: function () {
            pleaseWaitDiv.modal('hide');
        },
    };
})();
```

**page.html**

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<button type="submit" class="button btn-primary radius pull-right" onclick="waitBar.showPleaseWait()">Submit</button>

<script src="~/Scripts/test.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

When I click the submit button, the page darkens but the progress bar modal isn't displayed. Anybody have any ideas??

Comment: share your HTML and create a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) with your code

Comment: I'm not sure how to use fiddle properly, I tried this http://jsfiddle.net/m5p37d75/2/ but I'm getting `Uncaught ReferenceError: myApp is not defined`

Comment: In _Frameworks & Extensions_ of jsFiddle where you added jQuery, change _onload_ into _No wrap - in <head>_. Otherwise jsFiddle surrounds your code with a `$(function() { ... });` document ready function making the `myApp` a variable private to the function instead of a global one.

Comment: I don't see the `pleaseWaitDiv` div being added to the DOM in your JavaScript, not sure if that's needed frankly (as Bootstrap's modal js might do so). Why don't you add the `html` of the modal directly into the html code?

Comment: Thanks for the fiddle advice @ckuijjer. That might be a good idea actually, can you post an example? Also I think the problem might be partly related to the `hide` attribute in `'<div class="modal hide"`

Comment: The `.hide` class might very well be an issue. See my answer below for an example using html instead of having the JavaScript render it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would move the html of the modal dialog into the html document instead of it being defined in JavaScript. I've reimplemented the modal dialog as some of the html of the tutorial feels fishy.

```js
function show() {
  $('#pleaseWaitDialog').modal();
  
  // just for the example hide the modal after 5 seconds
  window.setTimeout(close, 5000);
}

function close() {
  $('#pleaseWaitDialog').modal('hide');
}
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<button id="btn" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="show();">Submit</button>

<div id="pleaseWaitDialog" class="modal" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h1>Processing...</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="progress progress-striped active">
          <div class="progress-bar" style="width: 100%;"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
```

Comment: Hi i am using this modal progress bar in form submission. how can I set window.setTimeout as loading time of form submission